# How to redirect a 404 page to my Home page?

Tags: html, redirect

Suppose this is my current website:

```
 www.mywebsite.com
```

What I'm trying to do is redirect any 404 pages to my Home pages

So, say

```
www.mywebsite.com/xyzz (page not found-404)
```

redirects to

```
www.mywebsite.com (Home page of website)
```

Comment: What are you even asking? Please rephrase your question

Comment: I Mean How to Change Notfound Page Url To Home Page Url this is my not found url http://sportsbeech.net/mmskksjsjs  how to set auto refresh to home page url this type of errors ?

Answer (score -1):

Put the following in your 404.php page

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".get_bloginfo('url'));
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!